# Show loader until all of requests completed

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a couple of requests in my React app when it initializes (in index.js)

```
store.dispatch(pagesRequest());
store.dispatch(articlesRequest());

if (localStorage.ACCESS_TOKEN) {
  store.dispatch(profileRequest());
  store.dispatch(notificationsRequest());
}
```

I want to show a full-screen loader until all of them are completed/errored. What is the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, its better way to dispatch one action for this requests e.g `initialize()`
Then, in saga listen for this action:

```js
yield takeEvery(initialize, function* (action) {
  const [pages, articles, ...] = yield all([
    call(fetch, '/pages'),
    call(fetch, '/articles'),
    ...
  ])
}
```